# Compiled JNI library (libmupdf.so), working fine for android 2.2 & Android emulator, but failing on android 2.1

Tags: android, android-emulator, java-native-interface, shared-libraries, android-ndk

I was able to build the mupdf library for android (libmupdf.so) and I got it working on the emulator. I have used the ndk: android-ndk-r5b & android-ndk-r4b, both work fine.

I have an app. that calls the mupdf library to read a PDF & save it as jpg files to the sdcard.

This works fine on the **emulator (both 2.1 and 2.2)** as well as on an **Android 2.2 device API level 8** (LG Optimus).

However, on the **Samsung Galaxy S (Android 2.1-update1 API level 7)**, the app installs fine, but on running, I'm getting the error :

> ERROR/AndroidRuntime: Caused by:
>   java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:
>   Library mupdf not found

I have tried building the library with ndk-r5b as well as prev. versions - ndk-r4, ndk-3 and ndk-r4b. There seems to be no change :(

Any ideas on what might be causing the error?!?! Any suggestions / help is appreciated.

Comment: hii @Roy Samuel I have got a problem while making libmupdf.so file it gives me error while i compiling the code from CMD D:/android-ndk-r8/mupdf-1.0-source/android//jni/mupdf.c:195: error: 'ctm' undecl
ared (first use in this function)
D:/android-ndk-r8/mupdf-1.0-source/android//jni/mupdf.c:195: error: 'currentMedi
abox' undeclared (first use in this function) can u help me to solve this errors.Thanks

Comment: I think you haven't included all the dependent header files for mupdf. Go through the project src, and ascertain all header files are included. That's the only reason I can see for this error.

Comment: But i can download the project from Mupdf website then how it is possible that some files are missing if so then can you suggest me any good tutorial from where i got full code.

Comment: While compiling the mupdf library, there are sources from other independent projects like libjpeg, some packages for font support etc.  I had obtained the source code for these projects independently, when I discovered there were discrepancies like the error you've mentioned. Try finding the source for these packages, if you find it, post it here. I could try and help finding the sources, but currently, I am in another "context", so to speak.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The mupdf build file - Android.mk
>   included a library 'jnigraphics' which
>   is not required.
>
> Linking this library and running on
>   Android 2.2 device or the emulator
>   (2.2 or 2.1) does not cause any
>   problems. However, if this library is
>   included and then run on an Android
>   2.1 device, (I used a Galaxy SI9000 Android 2.1-update1) causes an Android
>   runtime error, 'Library mupdf not
>   found'.

In the Android.mk file, there was a library being linked, named - 'libjnigraphics'. After the reference to this was removed, I was able to build for the Galaxy SI9000 Android 2.1-update1.

Comment: Hi. I am stuck in the same situation. Can you help me how to remove the reference. I don't know how. I deleted the line in Android.mk, but still it crashes on 2.1 with library not found but runs perfectly on 2.2

Answer (score 3):

There are some suggestions in the Dalvik [JNI Tips](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-jni.html) document.  The first thing to do is look at the logcat output above the exception and see if there's a dlopen() diagnostic.

Comment: Whoops, that broke a couple years back.  The document is now on the Android developer site.  Link updated.

Answer (score 0):

The mupdf build file - Android.mk included a library 'jnigraphics' which is not required.

Linking this library and running on Android 2.2 device or the emulator (2.2 or 2.1) does not cause any problems.
However, if this library is included and then run on an Android 2.1 device, (I used a Galaxy SI9000 Android 2.1-update1) causes an Android runtime error, 'Library mupdf not found'.

Comment: hi can you please help me I am unable to compile mupdf library

Comment: Hi TOX1C, Where are you stuck? Give me a proper description of your problem, and I can try helping you.

Comment: Hi roy thanks, I solved that problem and successfully compiled the library but there widget for displaying the pdf is very unprofessional it jerks on touch event I wanna know have you used their default view or create a custom one

Comment: Oh great! For my use case, I don't use a widget, but have the pdf rendered to JPG's and show them scaled as a 'drawable'. So yes, I have used the default view itself, and rendered the image. What is the widget that you are using?

Comment: I have also used the same approach I have a custom zoom Imageview and I am also displaying the images but the problem is once you zoom image the quality of PDF is not maintained and thats what the purpose of using PDF a renderer, here is my email id ingsaurabh@gmail.com I guess we can discuss it to make it more fancier and usable PDF renderer

Comment: The ImageView scales the jpg to be displayed, using BitmapFactory.Options's inSampleSize value. The jpeg file generated from mupdf is not affected.

Answer (score 0):

I had problems loading JNI library using android-ndk-r5b on Android 2.1-update1 devices (particularly Samsung Galaxy I9000), on Android 2.2/2.3 it was working fine. Using android-ndk-r7 gave me some compilation problems, but after i updated NDK to version android-ndk-r5c - my native library works perfectly on Android 2.1-update1/2.2/2.3  devices.